# Phonegap Ajax not working with phone but working in the browser

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I builded an app to insert a form value to MySQL database in a remote location. Insertion and retrieval are working fine with browser. When I convert the app into an APK file and try from my Android phone it is not working.

Ajax to insert:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://example.com/api/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#insert").val('Connecting...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "success") {
            alert("inserted");
            $("#insert").val('submit');
        } else if (data == "error") {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```

Configurations that I made:

In the html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*">
```

in the config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

and in the remote php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Why I am not able to connect from phone? Where I did the mistake?

Comment: at console is showing some error or message?

Comment: in browser its working fine....no error...after converting to apk its not working....means not connecting remote file....

Comment: Debug the app directly and look at the console

Comment: Debug app using chrome and Android 4+,  use `chrome://inspect/`

Comment: Some check list you have to do, 1)Check internet connection, 2)Is console error say any cross orgin like issue, 3) configure htaccess file correctly